# PHP if url contains xx add to vairable

Tags: php

So basically what I'm trying to do is if the url contents looks something like this:

`www.some.com/dir/?variable=VAR&variable2=VAR2`.

then the server would pick this up and I could add it to a variable like:

```
$var = [variable];
echo '<tag>'.$var.'</tag>';
```

and that would produce;

```
<tag>VAR</tag>
```

Sorry for the lack of code I just don't know how to do this with PHP and my searches are turning up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables are called [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and in PHP they can be accessed using the `$_GET` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

To use your example, the URL `www.some.com/dir/?variable=VAR&variable2=VAR2` will populate `$_GET['variable']` with `'VAR'` and `$_GET['variable2']` with `'VAR2'`.

You can access `$_GET` just like any other array from anywhere in your code so it should be straightforward to put its contents in your HTML code:

```php
<tag><?php echo $_GET['variable'] ?></tag>
<tag><?php echo $_GET['variable2'] ?></tag>
```

Do keep in mind this presents an [HTML injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). For example, the user could access the URL `www.some.com/dir/?variable=<script>doUnfortunateThings()</script>` and your script would dutifully render

```html
<tag><script>doUnfortunateThings()</script></tag>
```

Which would be executed by the browser when the page loads. This might be fine since only the user messing with the URL will see it, but depending on the rest of your page it could pose a security risk, and could even be made permanent by other scripts running on the page or on the server. It could also bypass any [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) settings your site is running under, depending on how that is configured if at all.

It is good practice to use the built-in PHP function [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on any user input before displaying it on the page to prevent any html tags from actually being rendered by the browser.

```php
<tag><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['variable']) ?></tag>
<tag><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['variable2']) ?></tag>
```

Comment: Yeah it will be going in with the specialchars would defo be doing that myself. Thanks for showing im going to go with this one as I like the way its presented pluss you have a well rounded answer with good info

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is iterate through your $_GET variables and print them out. 
$key is variable and $value is VAR . to print key value combo use this. to print just value remove the '$key is ' part.

```
<?php

foreach($_GET as $key=>$value)
{
echo "<tag>$key is $value</tag>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already know variable name from url then you can use it as array index:

```
$variable = $_GET["var_name"];
```

In your case:

```
$variable = $_GET["variable"];
$variable2 = $_GET["variable2"];
```